# global static(or non-static?) char array(buffer) with access from all c files

Tags: arrays, c, static, char, global

I have a header file , "temp.h" ,and several ".c" files which has "#include <temp.h>" header statements in each of them. And I define a global static char array in "temp.h" file as follows:

temp.h

```
  static char buffer[1000]={'A','B','C','\0'};
```

main.c

```
...
#include <temp.h>

int main()
{
  strcpy(buffer,"xyz");
  printf("\nBuffer : %s",buffer);
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

other.c

```
...
#include <temp.h>

int func()
{
  printf("\nInside func(), buffer : %s",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

and I compile all files with following command:

```
  gcc -o output.o main.c other.c
```

And I get no errors... and when run the "output.o" program ,
I **expect** a result like this:

```
 Buffer : xyz                     // Buffer was intentionally changed inside main
 Inside func(), buffer : xyz
```

**but I get:**

```
 Buffer : xyz                     // Buffer was intentionally changed inside main
 Inside func(), buffer : ABC      // doesn't get updated buffer content- why?
```

Why when I change the contents of a "(supposedly)global" static char array in one file inside any function scope (main or anyother), this change doesn't get reflected to all this char array's future references from any other file later, but instead in each file((or maybe inside in each function) its content is preserved??

How to make such that, I can use a specific part of char array (memory region) which is GLOBALLY accessible from all "files" and in their functions, and all references get correct readings?

thnx

Comment: There  are 2 different `buffer[]` as they are `static`.  Changing one does not change the other.  Don't use `static` is you want only 1 `buffer[]` .

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, but if I remove static keyword, then I get such error for each file or each function which refer to this variable.
```/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3GK74t.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `buffer'; /tmp/cc9HtEQv.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: suggest: Do not declare data in header files.  Rather declare 'extern type dataName'.  Then place the actual data declaration in one (only one) of the *.c files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current approach you have two copies of the array. Instead you need to *declare* the array in `temp.h` (with extern instead of static) and *define* it elsewhere, for instance in in `temp.c`:

temp.h:

```
#ifndef TEMP_H
#define TEMP_H

extern char buffer[1000];

#endif
```

temp.c:

```
#include "temp.h"

char buffer[1000] = "ABC";
```

You can also probably find a more descriptive name than *temp* for the module. It is also a good idea to add a prefix to the buffer variable, e.g. *temp_buffer* so that you avoid potential name clashes and make it easier for yourself and others to find where the array is declared.

Comment: When replaced keyword **static** with **extern**... Got even more errors and warnings such as: 
`
warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
  560 |       fprintf(stderr, "%s buffer here is:%s \n",buffer );|                                                                                
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckjaWGL.o: in function 'main':
temp.c:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to 'buffer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @mikkins If you have two `%s` in your format string you need to provide two strings after the format string.

Comment: %s->%n was my typo...STILL SAME ERRORS, even the same warning for mismatch of buffer as a char*....

Answer (score 0):

Ok...GOT IT!... now I solved!

In a singly included header file (( which is temp.h in question )) u must write:
`extern char buffer[];`

**Note:** single inclusion of this temp.h file can be achieved by "#ifndef-#endif" pairs in other ".c" and ".h" files of the compilation.

And next, include only in one of the files the following statement of definition:

`char buffer[1000];`

I hope this solution helps some guys.